# Android native application not connecting to Worklight Server

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, native, worklight-server

I'm trying to connect my android native application to worklight server, but i'm always getting the following error:

```
Unexpected errorCode occurred. Please try again.
```

I have the following code in my main activity:

```
connectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            connectBtn.setText("Connecting...");
            client = WLClient.createInstance(getApplicationContext());
            WLClient.getInstance().connect(new MyConnectListener());


        }
    });
```

and I created this class as a connect listener:

```
public class MyConnectListener implements WLResponseListener {

@Override
public void onSuccess(WLResponse wlResponse) {


    Log.d("Status", "CONNECTED");


}

@Override
public void onFailure(WLFailResponse wlFailResponse) {
    Log.d("Status", "FAILED CONNECTION "+ wlFailResponse.getErrorCode().getDescription().toString());
}
}
```

In my wlclient.properties i am using HTTPS with port value blank as mentioned in IBM tutorial.
any help with this problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to out the port for your connection if:
HTTPS : port = 443
HTTP : port = 80